# How can i display an error message in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am a beginner, and I have to write a code that calculates the area and circumference from the radius the user gives me. that part was easy, but the teacher also wanted me to only accept valid integers and have the user re-enter a value when his input is incorrect ...

so i was able to have it display the error message for every case except when they enter an negative integer:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class GetCircle
 {
     public static void main(String []args)
     {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     int radius;
     do {
    System.out.print("Please enter size of radius (Must be integer): ");
    while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.print("That is not a valid number, please try again :");
        input.next();
    }

    radius = input.nextInt();

    } while (radius < 0);

    System.out.println("The radius is: " + radius);

    }
}
```

and so this is what I get as a result:

> Please enter size of radius (Must be integer): aaa
>
> That is not a valid number, please try again :4.5555
>
> That is not a valid number, please try again :-5
>
> Please enter size of radius (Must be integer): -5
>
> Please enter size of radius (Must be integer): -8.777
>
> That is not a valid number, please try again :-4
>
> Please enter size of radius (Must be integer):

** so whenever its a negative integer it doesn't display the error message...

how can i fix this please?

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT. Also, please format your question so we can optimally assist you.

Comment: Hint: `-5` is OK regarding `hasNextInt`

Comment: i realize that, and i catch that error by going while ( radius < 0) at the bottom, but i want it to display the error message, and I am stuck. I don't know how to do it . i thought about using : while(!input.hasNextInt() || radius < 0) but that didnt work either.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it, but the simplest for you as a beginner would be to add an `if` statement in between your assignment to `radius` and the end of your outer while loop:

```
 if (radius < 0) {
    System.out.print("The radius must not be negative, please try again :");
 }
```

Comment: this doesn't work because you get :

That is not a valid number, please try again :-5
The radius must not be negative, please try again :Please enter size of radius (Must be integer):

so it repeats two messages now

Comment: Then just move your first System.out.print() call up before the 'do', so it is outside of the outer loop.

Comment: do you know how to use the same principle with JOptionPane?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, then you don't need to use `!input.hasNextInt()`. This is how you do it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetCircle {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int radius = 0;
    System.out.print("Please enter size of radius (Must be integer): ");
    while (true){
        if(input.hasNextInt()){ 
        radius = input.nextInt();
        if (radius < 0){
            System.out.println("That is not a valid number, please try again :");
            System.out.println("Please enter size of radius (Must be integer): ");              
        }   else {
        System.out.println("The radius is: " + radius);
        }
        } else {
            System.out.println("That is not a valid number, please try again :");
            System.out.println("Please enter size of radius (Must be integer): ");
            input.next();

        }
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: We still haven't learned to use try and catch yet and so I cannot use it ..

Comment: Please enter size of radius (Must be integer): -5
The radius is: -5

so it didnt show the error message...

Comment: but now when the user types 4.5, or a , something that is not an integer the program just exits....

Comment: if you look at the original code, it catches all the errors. so if the user types R, or 7.5 or -4 it makes him enter again. But when it is a negative integer, i cant get it to display the error message. that is the only thing that is wrong with it...

Comment: i did, but i have less than 15 reputation...

may i ask a couple questions?

Comment: @Brow if the answer works for you, could you consider accepting and upvoting the answer? thanks